# To get the Another column's id and add into 1st column in datatable using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the last column id and i want to add into the 1st column as well as i want to hide the last column header in datatable using jquery

```
table.api().columns(7).vsible(false); table.columns(7).visible(false);
```

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: table.api().columns(7).vsible(false);
table.columns(7).visible(false);
this two code is for hiding the last column header

Comment: Anyone can answer